# Recursion in C difficulties

Tags: c

I have a question about the recursion in C programming language.

I am reading a book about c, and I got this code that I didn't quite understand

first question:

```
void singTheSong(int numberOfBottles)
{
  if (numberOfBottles == 0)
  {
    printf("There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall. %d bottles of beer.\n",
           numberOfBottles, numberOfBottles);

    int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;

    printf("Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n",
           oneFewer);

    singTheSong(oneFewer); // This function calls itself!

    printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",
           numberOfBottles);
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  singTheSong(99);

  return 0;
}
```

so this is supposed to be a song.
I understand the if part

```
printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",
numberOfBottles);
```

I don't understand how the is increasing from 0 to 98

second question:

why isn't it going all the way to 99? It stops at 98.

please explain in simple english, because I don't use english as a main language (some difficulties)

thanks

Comment: It really helps with readability if you properly indent your code.

Comment: "how the is increasing from 0 to 98" - it doesn't. It decreases: `int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;`

Comment: Time to get out your debugger and step through some code.

Comment: @H2CO3 "beers on the wall" counts down, "empty bottles in the bin" counts up.

Comment: @barmar, actually, yes. (still quite a twisted question...)

Comment: Technically it is not counting up; it's just that "empty bottles in the bin" is printed at the end of each recursion step with the respective numberOfBottles value. Since the recursion call happens before printing this particular bit of information, you see the effect of "unwinding the recursion", with printing the numberOfBottles values of the deepest applicable recursion first (numberOfBottles = 1). For the outermost recursion, which is printed last,  numberOfBottles is obviously the original value. However, i don't understand how he could see a value range of 0 to 98, and not 1 to 99...

Comment: @elgonzo I agree ... I read it as going from 1 to 99 as well.

Comment: The code you posted will print the `"Put a bottle in the recycling..."` message for 1 to 99 bottles. Meanwhile, you claim that it is actually "from 0 to 98". That is impossible. The output will go from 1 to 99, period. You need to make sure that what you ran is the same as what you posted. Most likely your version of the code was printing `oneFewer` in that last `printf`, but here you posted code that prints `numberOfBottles` instead. You need to pay better attention to what you are running and what you are posting, since making false statements about the code will only create confusion.

Comment: @AndreyT the code is copied right off the book itself, not edited or something

Comment: @user1778002: Well, I'll repeat it again: the code you posted above will count up from 1 to 99 as it backtracks the recursion. Not from 0 to 98, but from 1 to 99. There can't be any argument about it. You have been told that many times by different posters here. Now, you claim that it counts up from 0 to 98. So, the only two possibilities here are: 1) the code you were running is different from what you posted here, 2) you claim about "0 to 98" is false. This is what I mean when I say that "you need to pay better attention to what you are running and what you are posting".

Comment: @user1778002: ... and it doesn't take a rocket scientist to figure out what happened. The code you posted above is NOT the code you were running. The code you were actually running had `oneFewer` in that last `printf` call. This is why you saw it count from "0 to 98". Meanwhile, the code you posted here will count from 1 to 99. I don't know which version is used in the book (most likely the one you see above), but what I do know for sure is that the code you posted here is NOT the code you were running.

Answer (score 3):

When thinking about recursion it helps to think about what is happening with the call stack.

In this case it's important to notice that

```
  printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",
       numberOfBottles);
```

Comes after:

```
 singTheSong(oneFewer);
```

So everything before `singTheSong()` is executed and then the recursive call happens adding a new stack frame.  No recycling print statements happen until after `numberOfBottles` gets to 0 bottles.

When `numberOfBottles` hits 0 the code rewinds, one by one, though all those stack frames.  Each frame has it's own copy of `numberOfBottles`.  So it starts rewinding at the top of the stack where it is 1, it then hits the end of that function call, pops that stack frame, and moves to the next frame where `numberOfBottles` is 2, then 3,... rewinding all the way back.

This shows off one of the risks of recursion- think about how much memory it used.  Not that recursion is inherently bad.  It can be good under certain situations when used wisely (like for teaching about how the call stack works).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand recursive programs like this is pretend you're the computer and follow the instructions by hand. Use a piece of paper to keep track of the variables in the program. Since there are two variables in the function, write on the paper:

```
numberOfBottles
oneFewer
```

Every time you call the function recursively, make a new column to the right for the current value, and when you return cross out those values. So when you first call `singTheSong`, you'll have:

```
numberOfBottles 99
oneFewer
```

(`oneFewer` is empty at the start). You say *99bottles of beer on the wall. 99 bottles of beer.* Then you assign `oneFewer`, so now you have:

```
numberOfBottles 99
oneFewer        98
```

and you say *Take one down, pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall.* Then you make the recursive call `singTheSong(oneFewer)`, and when you re-enter the function, you have:

```
numberOfBottles 99 98
oneFewer        98
```

You repeat all the above steps. If you keep doing this, eventually you'll get to the last case:

```
numberOfBottles 99 98 97 ... 3 2 1 0
oneFewer        98 97 96 ... 2 1 0
```

This time, the `(numberOfBottles == 0)` test at the beginning of the function will succeed. Instead of following the steps we did in all the previous times, it will just say *There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.* and return.

As I said above, when you return, you cross out the column in the variable table.

```
numberOfBottles 99 98 97 ... 3 2 1
oneFewer        98 97 96 ... 2 1 0
```

You then return to the steps of the function after it calls `singTheSong(oneFewer)`, which says *Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.* The function then returns again, so you cross out the last column:

```
numberOfBottles 99 98 97 ... 3 2
oneFewer        98 97 96 ... 2 1
```

and say *Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.* As you keep returning from each recursive call, you'll return to each of the saved values of `numberOfBottles`, so it will count up. Eventually you'll get back to the first column:

```
numberOfBottles 99
oneFewer        98
```

You'll say *Put a bottle in the recycling,99 empty bottles in the bin.* This time when you return, you'll get back to the original `main()` function, and you're done.

Comment: I have two questions. if you write a printf statement after singTheSong(oneFewer); it will be repeated the same amount of times as printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n numberOfBottles);. why? second question is: How can the function singTheSong and the variable oneFewer edit the value of numberOfBottles, it's not connected to, is it? else than that, a big thank for your help

Comment: Q1: I don't understand the confusion. If one statement is right after another, with no conditionals between them, they will of course be executed the same number of times. Q2: `numberOfBottles` is an argument to `singTheSong`. So every time the function is called, the variable is set to the parameter. I think you need to review how function arguments work, this is basic to all computer programming.

Answer (score 0):

"it is increasing from 0 to 98", because you only execute this part of the code when you stepped through all recursions (the function calls itself before this line) and now you are unrolling all the recursions.

second:
Watch your stack, don't use recursions!

mfg

Comment: "...don't use recursions!" is utterly rubbish. Recursion is a common programming technique. There a places where using recursion is inappropriate, but this does not justify such a statement.

Comment: singing the beer song with recursion may seem silly, but tree traversal is a natural for recursion, as is fibonacci, and other recursively defined functions.  "don't use recursion" is not an encouraging suggestion.